# Removing all variations of quotes and apostrophes using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove apostrophes and double quotes from a string, and have noticed there are various versions that create into the data I'm using depending on how its created. For instance, Word documents tend to use these:

```
It’s raining again. 
What do you mean by “weird”?
```

Whereas text editors are like this:

```
It's raining again.
What do you mean by "weird"?
```

As I go through the various character charts and data I've noticed that there are other variations of quotes and apostrophes, for example: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm

While I could go through and do a reasonable job of finding them all, is there an existing Perl regex or function that removes all variations of quotes and apostrophes?

Comment: Is [`[\p{Pi}\p{Pf}'"]`](https://regex101.com/r/cG9pZ1/1) what you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps a good approach would be to reverse the reasoning and remove all but wanted chars like `s/[^a-z0-9?._ \t- ]//g`

Comment: @stribizhev - your solution seems to work well! Thank you.

Comment: @nowox - creative, but there is a risk I will lose something valuable. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @WonkotheSane: I posted that as answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove all quotation marks and apostrophies, you can use

```
 [\p{Pi}\p{Pf}'"]
```

And replace with empty string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG9pZ1/1)

And [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/73dhRw):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
my $st = "“Quotes1” «Quotes2» ‘Quotes3’ 'Quotes4' \"Quotes5\"";
print "Before: $st\n";
$st =~ s/[\p{Pi}\p{Pf}'"]//g;
print "After: $st\n";
```

"Saying"

```
Before: “Quotes1” «Quotes2» ‘Quotes3’ 'Quotes4' "Quotes5"
After: Quotes1 Quotes2 Quotes3 Quotes4 Quotes5
```